# Hibernate: does filter on parent entity implicitly filters child entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, filter, annotations, parent-child

Suppose there are two entities EntityA and EntityB. 
Two tables are defined for both entities.
EntityB is child entity of EntityA.
Now in java pojos using hibernate annotation, i have defined two classes corresponding to tables EntityA and EntityB as below.

```
    @FilterDef(name = "myfilter", parameters = { @ParamDef(name = "year", type = "int") }, defaultCondition = ":year = year")

    public class EntityA

    {

       @OneToMany(mappedBy="EntityA")
       List<EntityB> getEntityBList()
       { 
       }

    } 


    public class EntityB
    {

      @ManyToOne
      @joincolumn(name="entityA_id") 
      EntityA getEntityA()
      {
      }

    }
```

Since I have got filter on EntityA. Is it implicit that EntityB will have objects loaded only which correspond to filtered objects of EntityA keeping in mind parent child relationship or do need to explicitly put filter on EntityB ?

Example if EntityA is filtered such that objects corresponding to year 2010 is loaded only. I want that loaded object of EntityB should be only which are child of EntityA objects corresponding to year 2010 only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `EntityB` is never queried directly, but is always loaded via `entityA.getEntityBList()` your filter will work. But if you directly query for `EntityB`, the results won't be filtered. Think of filters as restriction clauses included in the `WHERE` part of all SQL fired by Hibernate to load `EntityA`.

Comment: i have year column only in entityA table not in entityB. If suppose i want EntityB to be filtered also even if i directly query it. What should i do? Can u please provide me sample code.

Comment: No body answered my question for so many days. Am i not clear while making my points in question? what should i  to improve my question?

Comment: Thanks for answering all of my pending questions.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It turned out that you need to define a filter for EntityB in which you explicitly make a reference to EntityA, for example

```
<filter 
    name="myFilter" 
    condition="((select a.myProperty from EntityA a where a.id = entityA_id) = :myPropertyParam)" 
/>
```

As you can see I've used xml for my hibernate definitions. I'm sure that it's also possible with annotations.